# What's wrong with this monitor to laptop setup?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an Dell 27" 2707WFP UltraSharpTM Widescreen monitor. It's quite an old monitor, bought back in 2007, and it doesn't have any slots for an HDMI cable. Rather, it has a slot for a VGA cable.

Previously, I would plug the VGA cable from the computer into a DVI adapter, and then into my laptop. This worked fine.

However, I now have a new Windows 10 laptop with HDMI input, and with no slot for DVI input. I therefore plugged a DVI to HDMI adapter into my old setup. 
The setup looks like this.

[image: Cable setup]

Unfortunately, now when I plug the HDMI cable into my laptop, it doesn't recognize the monitor. It just says "Power save mode" and doesn't acknowledge any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your old DVI connector was a DVI-I type connector, which was both DVI-D and DVI-A - AKA, digital signals (which I seem to recall HDMI and DP are backward compatible with) and VGA compatible analog signals on the same connector

To do HDMI -> VGA I suspect you need an *active* converter, and the signal chain here goes "HDMI" -> "DVI-D" -> "VGA" and chances are the appropriate pins on the DVI part of your chain arn't connected to anything.

Get an *active* HDMI-> VGA converter which will translate the digital HDMI signals to analogue VGA.

Comment: Thus, I should get rid of the VGA->DVI part, and the DVI->HDMI part, and instead obtain a VGA->HDMI part?

Comment: You should either get rid of the white piece and get something like this: http://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Active-Female-Adapter/dp/B012DLMS1W/ ; or to be more simple, get rid of both the black and the white pieces and get something like this: http://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Active-Adapter-Micro-USB/dp/B00879DM56/